# What considerations determine whether to type and then cast to subtypes, or to use id?

Tags: objective-c, polymorphism, anonymous-types, subclassing

If I have a class hierarchy in which subclasses require use of more specific types than those specified in the superclasses' ivars, is it better to declare the superclass ivar as id, or to type it and then cast where necessary in the subclasses?

For example I have a superclass which uses an ivar of type Thing:

```
@interface SuperClass {
    Thing *_typedIvar; // OR 
    id anonIvar;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) Thing *_typedIvar; 
@property (nonatomic, retain, readwrite) id anonIvar; // OR
```

Then in a subclass implementation I want to use a SubThing to get at its methodNotInThing

```
@interface SubClass : SuperClass {
}
@implementation {

    - (void)aMethod {

       SubThing *subtypedIvar = (SubThing *)self.typedIvar;
       [subtypedIvar methodNotInThing];

       // OR

       [self.anonIvar methodNotInThing];


    }
}
```

(I'm assuming here that the subclass has appropriately assigned a SubThing to the ivar).

I've used both approaches (in my thus far short time using ObjC), and am never quite resolved regarding which is best. I like the compiler checking offered by use of real types, along with being able to use dot syntax where appropriate. But the constant casting in subclasses gets pretty ugly, requires more code, and somehow tastes worse to me (which is hardly an argument, I suppose). However I like the fact in the typed version that the superclass in effect documents what subclasses should do with the ivar.

Which of the above would be the better approach, and why?

Comment: I've accepted the answer below, but would stil be very interested to hear from anyone who prefers the id route, with reasoning. In particular, if anyone can give better shape to my inchoate suspicion of casting, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would argue that using real types is better, despite the drawback of having your code littered with casts.

- The programmer should be in control. Using id here is a bit careless.
- Easier to follow, and therefore easier to debug.
- While having casts everywhere may look messy, it forces you to be aware of what types you are expecting and again, this comes back to maintenance. It might work with id for right now, but if you have calls to id all over the place, how will you know why a particular one isn't working?

Comment: This is correct. You don't throw out type information unless you are forced to by the exciting dynamic language you're using (like Ruby). Then you throw all type information in the garbage (you can't even declare types) and you add a few hours of overtime to each day for writing unit tests. Some would say that those hours were gained by not having to type your types :)

Comment: I've never understood the appeal of typeless languages. It just feels lazy to me, but maybe I'm old school. ;)

Comment: I largely concur with you here, except for your comment that using id here would be 'careless'. It might be, but it also could be a reasoned response to the design issue here (ie. that subclasses assign different types to members).

Comment: I would be loathe to manage code which had such little structure that members weren't of at least a common supertype, or protocol.